# Expression Blend 3 Design Mode Exclamation Mark

Tags: wpf, expression-blend-3

I'm editing a ListViewItem template and I'm trying to add a custom control to the template but when I do I get a warning box surrounding my control that I add.

[Here is the pic.](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4031/4524456324_a21890a5fd_o.png)

Notice the image isn't re-sizing that is part of the custom control.

Why is this happening to my control?  I've used this control many times in my application with no problems re-sizing, etc., why the problems in the template?

Comment: -1: Link doesn't work. We can't allow image rot to make Stack Overflow like so many forums with once useful content made worthless by a series of broken images.

Comment: I agree, the question was from years ago and I now know to post content that will continue to be available in the questions and answers.  From what I remember the picture was a screenshot of the warning box mentioned. It's pretty common thing in the Expression Blend world, nothing special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to rebuild the application. Blend is telling you it's not sure what you're referring to.

UPDATE: On re-reading your post, now I'm not sure that a rebuild will work. I'll wait to see what rebuilding does (since that's always worked for me), then respond with further help.

Comment: Your right!  I was re-building the project in Visual Studio and then going to Expression Blend, I had to build it IN Expression Blend for it to work.  But I do have another problem.. the control isn't being sized in my template as it would in the rest of my application...

Comment: @Sentax What type of object is your control's parent?

Comment: CustomControl parent is Canvas, Canvas parent is the Template.  If I add my CustomControl to say a Window with a canvas, I can re-size the CustomControl and the images get re-sized correctly because of the binding width/height values in the CustomControl.  Just not in the template.  It's very strange.  Also in the Template, I don't see the image of my CustomControl, just the boundaries of the control where I can size it.  Very strange behavior.

Comment: @Sentax I don't _know_ that changing your Canvas to a Grid (even a grid without defined rows/columns) will solve your issue, but every time I've switched from a StackPanel or Canvas to a Grid, I've gotten more expected behavior from my controls. I believe it has to do with the fact that a Grid stretches to its container, so any control inside it acts "like it should" rather than having to worry about defining widths/heights for it. Give it a try and see if it helps.